# How install Ubuntu without create a new partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I want to try Ubuntu but I don't want to create a new partition on my disk.
I have Windows XP. 
And I don't want to use Live CD.

Answer (score 4):

Use Wubi. It lets you install it through Windows without booting up the Live CD.

Comment: I love this method.

Answer (score 3):

either you can use VirtualBox or VMware or else simply use wubi and [install Ubuntu inside Windows as another software](http://technofriends.in/2008/08/02/installing-ubuntu-on-windows-using-wubi/)!

Comment: Neat advice, but good hardware is required for a nice experience with the guest OS.